# grouping of dropdownlist controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 set of dropdownlist controls in asp.net page i want to create one set in one group and other set as one group. eg there are 15 dropdownlist which indicates internal dropdown and other 15 dropdownlist indicates as external drop down.

Comment: [<fieldset> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/fieldset) maybe?

Comment: your question is not clear explain it bit more.